# HANA: parsing string to timestamp with fractional seconds

Tags: parsing, timestamp, hana

I need to parse a varchar column with the following format into a Hana timestamp:

`02-JUN-17 09.10.51.633570 AM`

I have tried this function:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('02-JUN-17 09.10.51.633570 AM','DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.FF6') FROM dummy
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

```
    Could not execute 'SELECT to_timestamp('02-JUN-17 09.10.51.633570 AM','DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.FF6') FROM dummy'
[303]: invalid DATE, TIME or TIMESTAMP value: Error while parsing '02-JUN-17 09.10.51.633570 AM' in format 'DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.FF6' as DATE/TIME at function to_timestamp() (at pos 7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the `AM/PM` placeholder in the format pattern string.

```
SELECT   
       to_timestamp('02-JUN-17 09.10.51.633570 AM',
                    'DD-MON-YY HH12.MI.SS.FF6 AM') 
FROM dummy;
```

works just fine.